# Setting order of categorical columns in Altair histogram

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Trying to swap order of columns in histogram.

```
data = {'Age group': {0: '0 - 4', 1: '12 - 16', 2: '5 - 11', 3: 'not specified'},
 'Count': {0: 81.0, 1: 86.0, 2: 175.0, 3: 0.0}}

dp = pd.DataFrame(data)

alt.Chart(dp).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Age group:N', title='Age group'),
    y='Count:Q',
    tooltip=['Age group', 'Count']
).properties(title='Number of children in voucher', width=400)
```

[image]

Just want to swap the order and can't find a way of doing it.

Comment: Sounds like you need `dp.sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False, inplace=True, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Alt.X`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.X.html) *schema* has a `sort` parameter that accepts [an array specifying the field values in preferred order](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html#sort-array) :

```
X_ORDER = ["0 - 4", "5 - 11", "12 - 16", "not specified"] # >> set an order

alt.Chart(dp).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X(
        "Age group:N",
        title="Age group",
        sort=X_ORDER, # >> add this line
    ),
    y="Count:Q",
    tooltip=["Age group", "Count"],
).properties(title="Number of children in voucher", width=400)
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the category order directly in altair via `sort`, altair is also able to infer the order from the pandas dataframe when you work with categorical data (which can be preferable for other pandas operations as well):

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Age group': {0: '0 - 4', 1: '12 - 16', 2: '5 - 11', 3: 'not specified'},
    'Count': {0: 81.0, 1: 86.0, 2: 175.0, 3: 0.0}
})

data['Age group'] = pd.Categorical(
    data['Age group'],
    ['0 - 4', '5 - 11', '12 - 16', 'not specified'],
    ordered=True
)

alt.Chart(data, title='Number of children in voucher', width=200).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Age group',
    y='Count:Q',
    tooltip=['Age group', 'Count']
)
```

[image]